# is it possible to set a where clause between values of an array

Tags: sql, db2

So a little bit of backstory is I am working with a program that uses SQL filters to sort/rate freight bills. The problem is that it can only be 256 characters long. So what I was trying to do was using the built in select statement group like rates for various zip codes.

```
select * from tlorder
where blank = blank
and.......
```

Thats the default SQL so I added the following: Q_INT is a custom stored procedure.

```
Q_INT(start_zone) between 55001 and 56799 
and (Q_INT(end_zone) (between 55001 AND 56799
OR Q_INT(end_zone) between 58001 AND 58299
OR Q_INT(end_zone) between 57001 AND 57299
or Q_INT(end_zone) between 50301 AND 50399
or Q_INT(end_zone) between 51001 AND 51399
or Q_INT(end_zone) between 54001 AND 54099
or Q_INT(end_zone) between 54601 AND 54899)
```

And this works only its to long so is there a way to set 2 arrays and use that in the end_zone part? Like...

```
and Q_INT(end_zone) between Array[1,12,23] and Array[11,22,33]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try where Q_INT(end_zone) IN (1,12,23, ....)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this (tested on DB2 System i V7r1)

```
 select * 
 from yourtable f1
 inner join table(
                   values 
                   (55001, 56799), 
                   (58001, 58299),
                   (57001, 57299),
                   (50301, 50399),
                   (51001, 51399),
                   (54001, 54099),
                   (54601, 54899)
             ) f2(minval, maxval)
 on Q_INT(f1.end_zone) between f2.minval and f2.maxval
 where Q_INT(f1.start_zone) between 55001 and 56799
```

Answer (score -1):

For efficiency, what I would do first is create a table variable with number range (protip: ideally have a permanent Integers table in your database instead of this):

```
declare @ints table (
    number int not null primary key
    )

insert @ints
select row_number() over (order by pk_column)
from some_table_with_large_number_of_rows
```

Second thing to do is create a CTE with Q_INT(end_zone) calculated so that you are not calling that function bozillion times:

```
;with cte as (
    select *,
        Q_INT(start_zone) as qintsz,
        Q_INT(end_zone) as qintez
    from tlorder
    where blank = blank
    and.......
)
```

Then, voila:

```
select *
from cte
inner join @ints as a
on cte.qintsz = a.number
inner join @ints as b
on cte.qintez = b.number
where a.number between 55001 and 56799
and (
    b.number between 58001 AND 58299
    or
    b.number between 57001 AND 57299
    or 
    b.number between 50301 AND 50399
    or 
    b.number between 51001 AND 51399
    or 
    b.number between 54001 AND 54099
    or 
    b.number between 54601 AND 54899
    )
```

Comment: Won't work because it is a preset SQL that you can only edit the where clause and you only have 256 characters to do it with.

Comment: But, but my large and beautiful squizzles?! Oh well, I don't know how you deal with such restrictive SQL platforms @Landers but I'm not sure what you can do in such situations.

Comment: Yeah its definitely a pain. Full SQL usability but you better do it in 256 characters or less lol.